# Installing a new Ceiling Fan with strange existing wiring

Tags: ceiling-fan

[image]

I'm trying to install a ceiling fan with light kit after removing a 35+ year old light fixture and I'm really confused because there are 6 wires (3 black and 3 white) in total coming out of the box and the stripped copper wire is screwed into the box. 2 of the blacks and one of the whites are capped together, 2 of the whites are capped off together and one if the blacks is capped off alone. When I researched the wiring solution, there was none specific to a ceiling fan install, so I used a fixture install solution as follows: "The straight answer is the two whites together go to the white, or neutral, of the fixture. The single black goes to the black, or hot, of the fixture. Leave the other splice alone, just fold it back in the box." The only thing I did differently was combined the ceiling blue & black wires and capped it to the single black wire from the box. Unfortunately, the ceiling fan did not turn on at all. HELP!

Comment: How was the previous fixture connected? Did you remember to turn on the switch on the wall?

Comment: Are you sure that the existing box is a fan-rated type? I suspect it isn't...also, can you get us a clearer shot into the box without that bracket in the way?

Comment: I removed a light kit that had 2 round fluorescent bulbs connected to it. I also did nothing the existing wiring coming out of the box. I only disconnected the lighting wires.  Prior to removing this light kit, I installed a ceiling fan in a sun room that was only wired for a light kit about 15-years ago and that ceiling fan install was very easy due to the very common and newer existing wiring configuration.  I hope the newer picture and comments help.

Comment: If you pull on the wires coming out of the fitting on the right side of your photo, do they move a bit?

Comment: There is little to no movement when I do that.

Comment: This is not confusing.  The two whites are neutral.  The single black is switched hot.  The two blacks and a white are hot, and sending hot to the switch via a re-purposed white.  (That re-purposed white should be taped black at both ends except that wasn’t done consistently in years past).  Do you know where the switch is?  Is it good?

Comment: I'm following the instructions provided by Tyson, but I have a few related questions: 1) Please clarify if you are telling me to separate the re-purposed white wire from the two black wire and "Taped it Back" on ends? NOTE: Currently, the switch has a white wire connected to the top screw & a black wire connected to the bottom switch screw. 2) Do I combine all 3 of the "Hot" black wires together?
3) And combine all of the white wires?